# vscode builds, creates exe files, suddenly doesn't launch anymore (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, exe, launch

Using raylib and C++, VSCode had been building, creating and running the .exe file from main whenever I would hit F5.  However, suddenly it stopped and I can't figure out why.

Once it's done building and creating the .exe terminal just says: ***"Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it".***

The .exe file gets created and is put in the folder.  How can I get it to go back to build, create and run the .exe when hitting F5?

**tasks.json**

```
{

            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gcc.exe"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": false
            }
          ],
          "windows": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gdb.exe",
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build debug"
        },
        {
          "name": "Run",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "windows": {
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gdb.exe"
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build release",
        }
      ]
    }
```

gdb.exe is where it's supposed to be:
[image]

The problem even happens on the sample template which was working just up till an hour ago:
https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/VSCode/.vscode

Comment: you need a launch.json to execute the exe file...

Comment: thanks, i just added it to the question

Comment: Can you put a cin and see if it stops for user input?

Comment: figured it out...was a problem with the Microsoft C/C++ extension.  I don't exactly know why the insider channel broke the debugging though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the Microsoft C/C++ Extension.  After switching to 'Default', which basically downgrades from to a stable version I guess, things worked as normal again.

It was automatically set to 'insiders' channel and I don't know why but version 1.6 isn't properly launching the debugger or the exe (this stuff is way over my head).  Probably not good for Microsoft to force the 'insiders' channel if stuff is broken.

[image]